# Images/Videos CDN URL - Detect file type/extension

Tags: url, instagram, cdn, facebook-messenger, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Story Mention rendering according to IG messenger graph API.

IG webhooks sends the payload URL of the media as CDN URLs that are extensionless,
which means I can't detect the file type(could be any kind of image or a video file).
The purpose is to render the URL to an HTML element and to prevent saving some file extensions.

Did anybody find out how to get this information?

An example for IG CDN URL
https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=17952754300482708&signature=AbxVoHUcW3qKGZvE0FwrbpSEKBqkYGH9wFDUY9xnywlxxek8lWtrTwE173Sxhta9jbp0bgDiL17IpyiI82vqHGNPUD1wdMUZphwQOggW-_877cCI1BxaY_aDUZ8hj5OwmHK9E8OnSybqtMVmGXCX_hBF399t1Hb44zspeL3d9NWb9rib

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retrieve the content type by making a request with node-fetch.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const response = await fetch(mediaUrl, { method: 'HEAD' });
const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
```

Comment: But then you need to make 2 requests. One to know the content-type and the second to actually download/save the file. That means that if the file is a 3MB video, you will consume 6MB in data transfer. Is it possible to use a Nodejs library to download the file but then change the extension after it has been downloaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import requests
res = requests.head(url)
print res.headers
```